# Qt Download more then 15 files dont work based on downloadmanager example

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have simple Qt application that opens one worker thread in this worker thread 
im downloading files, image files always more then 20 ( it can be 50 also ).
For the download manager I took the DownloadManager project that is in the Main Qt Example dir
and used that, I just filled the QStringList with URL's and sent it to the DownloadManager   object instance.

But the download doesn't work as I expected, its not downloading all the files and always stops after 15-20 files any idea why?

Comment: Please the code of what it is you're doing.  Without code we cannot help you much.

Comment: this is allot of code , if you have the Qt framework just pass more then 25 links into DownloadManager example and you will see it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You're probably limiting on the number of simultaneous threads.

Comment: Web servers will generally limit the number of connections from a single host.  Try queuing your requests.